# when submitting a form, bootstrap modal opens, but when clicking the ok button, it's not working

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a form to update mysqli database with php codes. The codes are fine and when I submit the form the database updates and that means it works fine. But I want to receive a confirmation bootstrap modal before submitting the form. For it I used the following codes. Here the modal opens, but when clicking the OK button it's not working.

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" name="submit" value="submit" type="submit" data-condition="salaryinfo" data-toggle="modal-confirm" data-message="Are you sure?" data-title="Hi you!" data-target="#submit-confirm">Submit</button>         

          </form>
          <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="submit-confirm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-confirm="modal">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- For modal -->
<script src="js/confirm-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
function salaryinfo(){
            return true;
        };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        //modal delete confirm
        $('button[data-toggle="modal-confirm"]').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var self = $(this);
            var message = self.data('message');
            var title = self.data('title');
            var target = $(self.data('target'));
            var condition = self.data('condition');
            if( target.length == 1) {
                target.find('.modal-title').html(title);
                target.find('.modal-body').html(message);
                var showModal = true;
                var fn = window[condition];
                if(typeof fn === 'function') {
                    showModal = fn(condition);
                }
                if( showModal ) {
                    target.on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
                        target.find('button[data-confirm="modal"]').click(function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            var parentForm = self.closest('form');
                            console.log(parentForm.html());
                            if( parentForm.length == 1 ) {
                                parentForm.submit();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    target.modal({ show: true });
                };
            };
        });
    });    
    </script>
```

Any suggestion for a working modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already submitting the form before the modal opens because your button has the value submit:

`<button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" name="submit" value="submit" type="submit" data-condition="salaryinfo" data-toggle="modal-confirm" data-message="Are you sure?" data-title="Hi you!" data-target="#submit-confirm">Submit</button>`

So just make that a normal button with a data toggle to your modal.

And then make the confirm button on your modal, to have the value of submit.

You also need to include your modal within your `<form> </form>`

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the form submission to the Ok button instead of the Submit button.

Click on the `Submit` button: **open the modal**.
Click on the `Ok` button: **submit the form**

Assign an ID to your form `<form id='my_form'>`.

Assign an ID to your `Ok` button
`<button id='my_ok_button' type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-confirm="modal">OK</button>`

Bind the form submission to your `Ok` button

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).on('click', '#my_ok_button', function() {
        $('#my_form').submit();
    })    
</script>
```

You need to include jQuery for this script to work.